# Read invisible data from table with htmlagilitypack

Tags: c#, html, html-agility-pack

I have this html with table.
I can get "col1" and "col2" but I don't know how to get also value of "data-index", "data-name":

```
<table class="footable table" id="footable">
<tbody>
<tr class="trclass red" data-index="123" data-name="Apple">
<td class="col1" >Green</td>
<td class="col2" >1.25</td>
</td></tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

What I have tried:

```
    public static void Main()
    {
        var html =
        @"<html>
        <tbody>
        <table id=\'footable\'>
            <tr class=\'trclass red\' data-index=\'123\' data-name=\'Apple\'>
            <td class=\'col1\' >Green</td>
            <td class=\'col2\' > 1.25</td>
        </table>
        </tbody></html>";

        var htmlDoc = new HtmlDocument();
        htmlDoc.LoadHtml(html);

        var tbody = htmlDoc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//table[contains(@id, 'foo')]//tr//td");

        foreach(var nob in tbody)
        {
             Console.Write(nob.InnerHtml);  
        }
    }
```

I know that I can use nob.Attributes["data-index"], but my data is in **tr** before **td** where are my "Green" and "1.25".

Comment: Why can't you just change your XPath to select the tr instead of the td (i.e. lose the `//td` at the end), then you can  use the `nob.Attributes["data-index"]` ?

Comment: I want all, value of data-index, data-name and value of td (col1, col2....)